# Problem I Face while trying Number Recognition Using Tensorflow mnist

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

In my OpenCV project, I'm aiming to read a sudoku table, divide it into individual cells, and recognize the numbers. The rest is mostly sudoku solving.

I'm stuck on recognizing the numbers part. I decided to use minst dataset to train the model. For a reason that I couldn't figure out, the program always recognizes the digit wrong. I'll explain further with my code below.

This is my code for the recognition part:

```py
(ds_train, ds_test), ds_info = tfds.load(
    'mnist',
    split=['train', 'test'],
    shuffle_files=True,
    as_supervised=True,
    with_info=True,
)


def normalize_img(image, label):
    """Normalizes images: `uint8` -> `float32`."""
    return tf.cast(image, tf.float32) / 255., label


ds_train = ds_train.map(normalize_img, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
ds_train = ds_train.cache()
ds_train = ds_train.shuffle(ds_info.splits['train'].num_examples)
ds_train = ds_train.batch(128)
ds_train = ds_train.prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

ds_test = ds_test.map(normalize_img, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
ds_test = ds_test.batch(128)
ds_test = ds_test.cache()
ds_test = ds_test.prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28, 1)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)
])
model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.legacy.Adam(0.001),
    loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()],
)

model.fit(
    ds_train,
    epochs=6,
    validation_data=ds_test,
)
sample = cv.cvtColor(sample, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
sample = cv.resize(sample, (28, 28))

view_image(sample)
sample = np.invert(np.array([sample]))

prediction = model.predict(sample)
print(np.argmax(prediction))

sample = np.invert(np.array([sample])).reshape((28, 28, 1))
cv.imshow("test", sample)
cv.waitKey(0)
```

This is my image before the processing and after.

First form of my image:

[image: First form of my image]

My image after rescaling to 28x28:

[image: My image after rescaling to 28x28]

The model predicts my image as 3 constantly. I don't know the reason behind this.

I tried to implement a solution in which I trained the model with a size of 300x300 and converted my image to 300x300 rather than 28x28, but the result didn't change.

I don't know if I implemented that solution wrong, but I hope that you can help me with this.

EDIT

```py
size = 300
(ds_train, ds_test), ds_info = tfds.load(
    'mnist',
    split=['train', 'test'],
    shuffle_files=True,
    as_supervised=True,
    with_info=True,
)


def resize_img(image, label):
    return tf.image.resize(image, (size, size)), label


ds_train = ds_train.map(resize_img, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
ds_test = ds_test.map(resize_img, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)


def normalize_img(image, label):
    """Normalizes images: `uint8` -> `float32`."""
    return tf.cast(image, tf.float32) / 255., label


ds_train = ds_train.map(normalize_img, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
ds_train = ds_train.cache()
ds_train = ds_train.shuffle(ds_info.splits['train'].num_examples)
ds_train = ds_train.batch(128)
ds_train = ds_train.prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

ds_test = ds_test.map(normalize_img, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
ds_test = ds_test.batch(128)
ds_test = ds_test.cache()
ds_test = ds_test.prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(size, size, 1)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)
])
model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.legacy.Adam(0.001),
    loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()],
)

model.fit(
    ds_train,
    epochs=6,
    validation_data=ds_test,
)
sample = cv.cvtColor(sample, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
sample = cv.resize(sample, (size, size))

view_image(sample)
sample = np.invert(np.array([sample]))

prediction = model.predict(sample)
print(np.argmax(prediction))

for class_index, prob in enumerate(prediction[0]):
    print(f'Class {class_index}: Probability {prob}')

sample = np.invert(np.array([sample])).reshape((size, size, 1))
cv.imshow("test", sample)
cv.waitKey(0)
```

This is the code that I wrote to process all of the images in 300x300 format. Of course, it's slower than the 28x28, but I thought that It would increase the accuracy. unfortunately, it didn't change anything.

Comment: You cannot use the MNIST dataset for this, it is not meant to train a general digit recognition system, its just an academic dataset.

Comment: What does this mean? I didn't get it. Can you explain more, please?

Comment: the MNIST dataset contains handwritten digits. if you want to train your model to handle inversion (black on white), you need to train it for that. if your model needs to handle debris like the black line on the left edge of your sample picture, you also need to train it for that.

Comment: You can look into binary thresholding and inversing the colors (MNIST is white numbers on black background). You can also try to remove the dark bars with morphological operations from openCV. Aslo, the numbers here are not handwritten, so an OCR scan could get you the same results.